# Windows - how can I create event log with "Comment" level?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, event-viewer

How can I create a "comment" Level of a log manually ?
in number the level is 5.
Here an image:[image]

[image: CommentLevel(5)]

Comment: [Write-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Write-EventLog)?

Comment: You should provide some kind of code / error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing myself and think I got what you are looking for.

```
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType "Information" -EventId 666 -Message "Events are fun"  -Category 1  -Source "Application"
```

[image]

[image]
Source: [Write-Eventlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)

Comment: Hello this is not an "information" entrytype. This is a "Comment" type. Information type  = loglevel 4, comment type = loglevel 5, write-eventlog cannot create log with entrytype of "comment"

Answer (score 0):

The logs is "Verbose" type from information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).